# How to make a new column of data from existing data for 1 column in php

Tags: php, laravel

I have an array of different data for different column, I have to make a new column from existing data if count goes greater than 1.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [ID_NO] => 11
                [ID_NAME_EN] => ABC-2
                [CAR_NO] => 9
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [car_id] => ABCD89620
            )

        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [seat_id] => FFGH70406
            )

        [3] => stdClass Object
            (
                [body_id] => IJKL08882
            )

    )
```

)

I want to make above array like this

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [ID_NO] => 11
                [ID_NAME_EN] => ABC-2
                [CAR_NO] => 9
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [car_id] => ABCD89620
                [car_id1] => ABCD5788
            )

        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [seat_id] => FFGH70406
            )

        [3] => stdClass Object
            (
                [body_id] => IJKL08882
            )

    )
```

)

how can I achieve this in laravel.I have to increase column if count goes up than 1, if count is 2 than I have to make 2 columns, if 3 than 3 and so on.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but generally speaking, if you're trying to dynamically create columns in your application, you are not structuring your database correctly. If there is a need for unique id data to be added as the app grows, what I would consider would be encoding json in a singular column. It could get a little hairy trying to query it with relations and what not, but it is doable.